# Finding the size of an HTML 5 web sql database size after creation

Tags: html, web-sql

I'm using HTML 5 Web SQL database in Safari.  I'm setting the database size to 5 MB.  After creating database the size increased, but I can't find out the new size of the database.  Where can I find the size of the database after creation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The database is stored on the client in different places:

- Windows: /Users/{user}/AppData/Apple Computer/Safari/Databases
- Safari: ~/Library/Safari/Databases

There is a master database file in this folder that points to your database in the relevant subfolder.  You can see the size of the database in Explorer/Finder.  I find, however, that the size of the database is dependent on the platform (and the database size varies greatly between Safari and Chrome).